# *Fixed* Ubuntu Server 18.04 is mounting my File System as Read-Only

Tags: server, filesystem, read-only

this morning my server was giving me errors like cracy, it starts but most services dont, after inspecting a bit i found out that for some reason out of the blue, my file system is being mounted as read-only, i havent touch the server in weeks and everything was working fine, i have nextcloud, onlyoffice and unify on them only, i do not know what trigger this but i need to fix it and im running out of options :S iv already tried:

Booting into recovery as root and do mount -o remount,rw / but it hits me with an error that the command is wrong

Checking my fstab file but everything seems to be ok, heres my fstab:

```
UUID=f8ab53bc-f6d3-4b89-bd63-47112c7055ae / ext4 defaults 0 0
/swap.img       none    swap    sw      0       0
```

and this is the result of my blkid:

```
/dev/sda2: UUID="f8ab53bc-f6d3-4b89-bd63-47112c7055ae" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="6210f34b-355f-4857-93f8-804098b20513"
```

as u can see, everything is correct, so i dont know what triggered this read-only file system thing or how to fix it, please help

Edit: i manage to fix it, somehow i dont know why and im trying to find an answer, when i booted my machine into live ubuntu desktop, modified the fstab file by just adding a # on a blank line and save it, when i reboot the vm everything works as it should and the system gets mounted as read write as it should and everything works again, i copied the faulty vm like 3 times and repeated the procedure the same way, just by doing any modification to the fstab file, fixed my problem, i do not know why or what is the root of this issue, but that fixed it –

Comment: May be disk failure is the culprit?

Comment: the ubuntu server is mounted on a vm, i already tried to move the vm to a diferent partition but i still get the same result :-(

Comment: But the system hosting the vm is ok?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen yes its ok, i also moved the vm to another machine and start it just to make sure and everything is the same, i dont think the culprit lies on the VM, but i dont know what to do to mount the file system again as rw :-(

Comment: `sudo journalctl -b 0` will show you system log messages, starting at the current boot. In the first few screens, you will see messages about your disk, and how it got mounted.

Comment: *"it hits me with an error that the command is wrong"* - what is the exact text of the message?

Comment: Try to `fsck` your virtual disk

Comment: ok i manage to fix it, somehow i dont know why and im trying to find an answer, when i booted my machine into live ubuntu desktop, modified the fstab file by just adding a # on a blank line and save it, when i reboot the vm everything works as it should and the system gets mounted as read write as it should and everything works again, i copied the faulty vm like 3 times and repeated the procedure the same way, just by doing any modification to the fstab file, fixed my problem, i do not know why or what is the root of this issue, but that fixed it